# Cannot open port 2000 on 127.0.0.1 adapter - how to find the reason?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, tcp, tcplistener

For months I haven't run a .NET application we develop, which worked fine last time around. In the meantime, I've updated my computer to Windows 10 Pro 1809 (as well as at home).

Today I tried running it, and it wasn't behaving properly. I debugged it and narrowed it down to an exception after the code attempts to start a TCP server on a configurable port, which is by default `2000`.

The exception is the following:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

It is thrown when this code is executed:

```
        listener = new TcpListener("127.0.0.1", 2000);
        listener.Start();
```

I did the normal diagnostic steps, to no avail:

- Is anything already listening on that port
- Disable firewall
- Re-enable the firewall then delete rules surrounding the application and the port in question
- Enable firewall logging to see if there's any evidence of it rejecting

So I quickly test the same in a PowerShell script:

```
$port = 2000
$listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener ("127.0.0.1", $port)
try 
{
    $listener.start()    
    Write-Output "Successfully opened port $port"
}
catch 
{
    Write-Error $_          
}
finally
{
    $listener.Stop()
}
```

And I get pretty much the same exception:
`Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "An attempt was made to access a socket in a
way forbidden by its access permissions"`

Next I decide to change the port to `3000` and it works fine.

Next I adapt the script to loop between ports from `1` to `2500` and get a bunch of failures, including ranges from `1657` to `2156` and `2179` to `2279`.

Where would one go next to find the root cause? What mechanism could Windows be using to reject the binding (?) attempt?

**UPDATE**

Tried this C# application and I get the same result:

```
namespace TcpBindTest
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1}), 2000);
            listener.Bind(endpoint);
            listener.Listen(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `netstat -ano` to see what's listening or try running your code as admin?  Antivirus software can also block specific port ranges.

Comment: @Zer0 yes I have tried `netstat`. My colleague is under the same network environment as me, and it all works on his computer (same antivirus, same group policies in the domain, etc)...

Comment: A co-worker ran into the same problem. He came across an MSDN post (I don't have the link with me) that asked to try stopping "Internet Connection Sharing" service and that seems to have worked. If I ever find out more about it, I'll post additional information.